# Probability 2 random points in 2 circles are within a contact distance

Tags: probability, estimation

Suppose I have a point randomly located in circle 1 (blue), and a point randomly located in circle 2 (red). I would like to know the probability that the 2 points are within a threshold distance of each other. Any suggestions?  Thanks.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhzDI.png)

This works quite well when the threshold distance is small (relative to the circle sizes):

probability = (A∩B/A) * (A∩B/B) * (PI*d^2/A∩B)

where:

- A is the area of circle 1
- B is the area of circle 2
- A∩B is the overlap area of circles A and B
- d is the threshold distance

But when d becomes close in size to the circle radii, the approximation breaks down. I can get a good estimate for the correct answer for r1, r2, and d by running a simple simulation (but this is too slow):

- place a point randomly in circle 1
- place a point randomly in circle 2
- keep track of the fraction of pairs that are within d.

Probably a refinement to the probability equation above would be sufficient.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: What does it mean for two points to be "within contact distance"?

Comment: I gather that your "points" are actually small circles, and that the "contact distance" is the diameter of those small circles. Is that right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I'm going to touch up the description above to make it clearer.

By "contact distance", I just meant the distance between the 2 points. Also, no, I'm not thinking of it as small circles inside the big circle. Just 2 randomly positioned points, one inside each circle. Thanks.

Comment: Let $S(r_1,r_2,a)$ is area of intersection of two disks of radiuses $r_1$, $r_2$ with distance $a$ between centers. One can get case expression for $S$. Then you need to integrate $S(d,r_2,a(p_1))$ over area of first disk. $p_1$ is point in the first disk. $a(p_1)$ is distance from point $p_1$ to center of second disk.

Comment: Mind that probability depends on four numbers: $r_1$, $r_2$, $d$ and distance between circles centers. One can scale to exclude one of four numbers.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Yes, I think it's right that I need to integrate over the area. A bit complicated but I think doable.